# Segmentation fault problem with object lists

Tags: c++, list, object, pointers, segmentation-fault

i'm doing a C++ project, a very simple video game. This game must have infinite levels, and every level has a random number of platforms.
I created an object for platform, here the hpp:

```
class platform {
protected:
    hitBox box;
public:
    platform (int a, int b, int c, int d);
    void print();
    hitBox getHitbox();
};
```

and an object for the level, that has a list of platforms in it, because the numbers of platforms can change for every level, here the hpp:

```
struct Pplatform {
    platform* plat;
    Pplatform* next;
};
typedef Pplatform* lPlatform;

hitBox newRandomPlat (hitBox where);

class level {
protected:
    int nlevel;                
    lPlatform platforms;           
public:
    level (int nl, bulletManager* bM);
    void print_platforms ();
    infoCrash check (hitBox ht, char d);  
    int lnumber ();                       
};
```

but in level.cpp i have and error of segmentation fault when I create a platform object in the list:

`this->platforms->plat = new platform (0, 1, COLS, 0);`

this line give me segmentation fault, i have tried to write it in different way like this:

```
platform plt = platform (0, 1, COLS, 0);
this->platforms->plat = &plt ;
```

but it doesn't work. Could u help me please? thank

Comment: Where are you allocating memory for the `Pplatform` that `level::platforms` points to?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], have you tried using a debugger to inspect the segfault? It will show you what exactly caused it.

Comment: `this->platforms->plat = &plt ;` Remember that the `&` takes the address of the local variable but does not extend it's lifetime in any way. When `plt` goes out of scope the `this->platforms->plat`  will point to an invalid address.

Comment: From the code you show your bug appears to be `platforms` has not been allocated. So you can't do `this->platforms->plat = anylocation` where `anylocation` is a pointer.

Comment: c++ has a very steep learning curve, so if you are doing this project to learn C++ then it is a good time to learn about objects lifetimes and ownership and to avoid using raw pointers and start using smart pointers, this code is more like C code than C++ code, if your objective was to make the game then you should probably start with a safer language, python and java come to mind, and there are game engines that don't require a lot of coding.

Comment: Luckily for you, segmentation faults (segfaults) are some of the easiest issues to catch and diagnose with your [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Have you debugged your program yet? What did your debugger tell you when you hit the segfault? What did the stack trace look like? What was the value of relevant variables in the stack frame where the problem occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation problem you are experiencing is most likely caused by accessing memory that was not properly allocated. You're attempting to set a value to `this->platforms->plat` in your code, but it appears that you haven't allocated memory for `this->platforms`.

You can try this revised code of your level constructor that uses the platform member:

```
level::level(int nl, bulletManager* bM) : nlevel(nl), platforms(nullptr) {
    
}
```

When you build a new platform, you must allocate memory for it dynamically and update the platforms list.